# Changing the created JSON object key when rendering a json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm rendering some json that outputs this

```
 render json: service.get_object_item(param)
[
    [0] "{"object_item":[{"count":1,"dueDate":"2021-02-23","dayCreated":23}]}"
]
```

I want to change the `object_item` array key to camel case so it will match the inner array casing.

```
[
    [0] "{"objectItem":[{"count":1,"dueDate":"2021-02-23","dayCreated":23}]}"
]
```

However it seems like it gets set when render gets called so I can't change it. I've only been able to omit it by doing `render json: service.get_object_item(param).to_json`.

Comment: That looks sort of but not quite like JSON. What's that output format?

Comment: It's an array and the json is inisde the array at key `object_item`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with this

```
render json: { objectItem: service.get_object_item(param) }
```

Which returns

```
[
    [0] "{"objectItem":[{"count":1,"dueDate":"2021-02-23","dayCreated":23}]}"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [active model serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and define the keys there, or you can use rails built in [transform_keys](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/transform_keys) function

Comment: I tried the `transform_keys` method but that didn't work. I think because the thing i want to transform is the key of an array, not a hash. json[0].transform_keys{ |key| key.camelize}
` and `json.transform_keys{ |key| key.camelize}` both had errors